# Return User To Admin Users and Undo Parental Controls

Tags: user-account, sudo, administrator, parental-controls

For a while, I had only one user, say, `User1`, on my Mac's High Sierra. Then there arose a need to have some parental controls. To do that I created a new user, say, `User2` and made it an admin while `User1` was the controlled one.

At present, the need to control is no longer there and all of the information that I need to use is still under `User1`. My questions are the following.

1. How can I add `User1` to sudo'ers?
2. Is there a way to get rid of `User2` account and restore `User1` to its original sole ownership?
3. How can I make sure all of the deleted user's info and storage is scrapped and freed?

Any help or advice is appreciated.

Comment: Habe you tried to just undo what you did before: disable parental control on u1, set u1 to admin, relogin as u1, delete u2?

Comment: to clarify, You want to make the user 1 the admin, and delete user 2, knowing you will loose all data with user 2.

Comment: @nohillside I have not. I didn't know whether it was going to be as straightforward as that.

Comment: @Buscar웃 Correct. Nothing of value was acquired for User2.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As User 2

- Open Users & Groups
- Unlock it with Password
- Disable (uncheck) parental controls for user 1
- Enable User 1 as Admin

Log out from User 2, log in as User 1

- Open Users & Groups
- Delete user 2 (you will be offered to save or not the user data)

Comment: Are you sure a user can delete itself? And if this is possible, how should u1 get admin rights afterwards?

Comment: @nohillside (patrix) what would I do without you watching my every step

Comment: What would the OP do if they end up without an admin user :-)